# Access servlets web application context URL from inside CSS/JS file

Tags: java, css, servlets

How can we access web application context url from inside the CSS/JS file on java web server?

We can map URL's (for background image for example) relatively with `url('../img/bg.gif')` etc. but this will not work with web application with mappings like:

- /shop/
- /shop/show/3/
- /shop/payment/

because browser will search for this file relative to current "virtual" directory.

Also, we can't universally map image URL global like `url('/images/bg.gif')`, **because we forces deployment in top-level directory** like `example.com/` (not `example.com/myproject/`).

How to avoid changing CSS/JS(ajax) URL's when changing application context URL?
It is possible to access aplication context in CSS file in easy way like accessing contextPath in default servlet wich serves those static files?

Comment: Why do you deploy in top-level directory ? O_o

Comment: I mean top-level url directory like `www.example.com`, but not `www.example.com/myproject`. So I mean deployed context url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (assuming you're using Tomcat, if not, look up the doc to find the correct servlet name to add the mapping):

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>fork</param-name> 
        <param-value>false</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name> 
        <param-value>false</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping> 
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you can add jsp el code in your css:

```
url('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/bg.gif')
```

This will make your CSS files serve MUCH slower, so take into account if you can do it with absolute pathing at the root.  We've used this approach in an app that allowed skinning of the CSS, so that we could output custom color schemes.